# How to use a system variable in NAnt script?

Tags: variables, system, nant

I'm looking for usage of such variables as %WinDir%, %ProgramFiles%, ect. in a NAnt script but I don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

${environment::get-variable('WinDir')}

Comment: just to throw this out there [`setenv`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc2/help/tasks/setenv.html) is a good complement to `get-variable` if one wishes to modify one of the variables

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [get-variable](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/environment.get-variable%28System.String%29.html) function.